# Отключить жёлтую обводку после использования автозаполнения

Tags: css

Пытаюсь не отключая полностью autofill убрать всё то, что он приносит в стили css. Пока что получилось всё, кроме жёлтой обводки(видно на скриншоте). Она возникает после того, как user этот самый autofill использовал. Как её убрать - не знаю, подскажите, пожалуйста.

Вот весь код, что относится к полям input

```
.login_input{
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 2vh;
  height: 4vh;
  width: 12vw;
  border: 0.2vh solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  outline:none;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: calc(10px + 0.5vw);
}
.login_input:focus{
  border: 0.3vh solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  border-radius: 2vh;
  outline:none;
}
.login_input:-webkit-autofill,
.login_input:-webkit-autofill:hover,
.login_input:-webkit-autofill:focus{
    -webkit-text-fill-color: white;
    box-shadow:inset 0 0 0 1000px #000;
    border: 0.2vh solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
}
```

[image: а вот как это выглядит].

Comment: это плохая тактика, лучше этого не делать, конечно. в статье про [autofill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:autofill) все об этом отмечено.

Comment: @DiD, довольно плохая поддержка, как по мне.